# Magento Admin Questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Which is the right tag for asking questions that are related to adminhtml programming and configuration questions?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very good question. To my mind:

- `backend` question should be related to backend programming, not admin interface
- `adminhtml` should be related to admin interface modifications
- `administration` or `configuration` should refer to admin interface howto's.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the tag `backend` would be right for the backend interface and `adminhtml` should be used for anything regarding backend coding.

This way you have a clear distinction between backend coding and backend interface like `System -> Configuration` and `Catalog -> Manage Products` questions